# HAML use .each() error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

When I use HAML .each function, I get an error notice below:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in xxxx#index
[stdin]:7:17: error: unexpected |
   @logs.each do |i|
 (in xxxx/item.hamlc)
```

And my hamlc file is:

```
%td= @mTime
%td= @operator
%td
  %table.table-condensed.table-bordered
    - @logs.each do |i|
      %tr
       %td= i
```

I have no idea why that happened.

Comment: it's not haml each, it's ruby each

Comment: yes! Thanks, I use for..in  and solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your indentation. You have to perfect indentation if you use HAML.

Comment: I change my code to use javascript for..in  and the problem solved. Thanks!